# How does created_at and updated_at get populated in test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I know that updated_at and created_at are populated via database triggers in rails but how does it work in case of test database that is created using schema.rb file. I know that schema.rb file is not capable of storing database trigger information.

Normally, to setup the test database, I use

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

and then I run the test cases, updated_at and created_at are always populated. How?

Edit: 
I can see that triggers were automatically created for tables in my development database.

```
Triggers:
    a_update_updated_at BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON items FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_updated_at()
    b_update_created_at BEFORE INSERT ON items FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_created_at()
```

Comment: Because they are not populated via triggers? :)

Comment: Are you sure? I can see triggers were automatically created for my tables in the development database.

Comment: ok, now that you have mentioned it. I think rails is using triggers for development and prod databases and application code for test databases. If true, this sounds like a hack

Comment: You can search SO and find a post with AR code, which points that AR fills out `created_at` and `updated_at` _without_ triggers. Also, I checked my Postgresql DBs and didn't find any triggers for timestamp columns.

Comment: May be you have specific DB, Rails version or gems ?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk Yeah, I saw that. That answer is two years old(assuming you saw the same post as me).

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.12, Rails 4.2 and I do not have any gem that is adding triggers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170830/discussion-between-xeon131-and-pavel-mikhailyuk).